# Dart Gmail API 'send' method returning DetailedApiRequestError

Tags: flutter, dart, gmail-api

I am rebuilding [my personal website in Flutter](https://github.com/ashtonjonesdev/ashton_jones_dev_website) and need to send an email after a form is filled out

WHAT: I am trying to send an email using the Gmail API Dart library

ERROR: DetailedApiRequestError(status: 400, message: Invalid value at 'message.raw' (TYPE_BYTES), Base64 decoding failed, when calling 'send'

Authentication is working fine. I followed the steps in [googleapis](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis) package to implement authentication, using a service account and the 'clientViaServiceAccount' method.

I followed the [Gmail API documentation for sending an email using the send method](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#python_1), creating a MimeMessage, formatting it in RFC 2822 and encoding it to base64url, creating a Message object and setting the 'raw' property to the encoded MimeMessage, and calling the GmailAPIs 'send' method.

The issue seems to be with the encoding of the MimeMessage.

I created a MimeMessage using [enough_mail package](https://pub.dev/packages/enough_mail) and set the message the Base 64 encoding

Here is a link to the project on Github: https://github.com/ashtonjonesdev/ashton_jones_dev_website
The 'send' method is in [consulting.dart](https://github.com/ashtonjonesdev/ashton_jones_dev_website/blob/master/lib/ui/widgets/consulting_tab.dart)

I appreciate your help! If you can help me solve this, I will give you a shoutout in my article

Send email code:

```
sendEmail()  async {

   print('sendEmail');

// Create a Mime Message and encode it using base64

MessageBuilder messageBuilder = MessageBuilder();

messageBuilder.from = [
  MailAddress('Ashton Jones', 'ashton@grapeworks.dev')
];

messageBuilder.to = [MailAddress('Ashton Jones', 'ashtonjonesdev@gmail.com')];

messageBuilder.subject = 'cool subject';

messageBuilder.text = 'cool text';

messageBuilder.encoding = MessageEncoding.base64;

// Added Rfc822 encoding
messageBuilder.contentType = ContentTypeHeader.from(MediaType.fromSubtype(MediaSubtype.messageRfc822));

messageBuilder.messageId = '1';

MimeMessage mimeMessage = messageBuilder.buildMimeMessage();


// Ensure body is also encoded as base64 and Rfc822
mimeMessage.body = BodyPart();
mimeMessage.body.contentType = ContentTypeHeader.from(MediaType.fromSubtype(MediaSubtype.messageRfc822));
mimeMessage.body.encoding = 'base64';

// Create a Message object and set the 'raw' property to the encoded String
Message message = Message();

// TODO Need to set the 'raw' property as the entire encoded MimeMessage
// TODO: Figure out if I need to encode the entire MimeMessage as a base 64 String here again (I already set the encoding of the MimeMessage to base64 on line 156)


// Should return the entire encoded MimeMessage
String encodedMimeMessage = mimeMessage.renderMessage();

// Error happening here
message.raw = encodedMimeMessage;

print('Encoded message: ${message.raw}');

// Send the email using the Gmail API 'send' method
// TODO: When I run this, I get an 'invalid value at 'message.raw' (TYPE_BYTES), Base64 decoding failed' error
Message messageCompleted =
    await _gmailApi.users.messages.send(message, 'me').catchError((error) {
  print(error);
});

print(messageCompleted);
```

}

initState code:

```
  @override
   void initState() {
   super.initState();

      print(
      'CREDENTIALS: Client ID: ${_credentials.clientId.toString()} | Client Secret: ${_credentials.privateKey}');

// Authenticate the credentials with the service account and use them to initialize the GmailAPI
clientViaServiceAccount(_credentials, scopes).then((AuthClient httpClient) {
  _gmailApi = GmailApi(httpClient);

  print('Users: ${_gmailApi.users}');
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think that you might have to encode your mimeMessage like this,

```
    message.raw = base64.encode(utf8.encode(mimeMessage.renderMessage()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented sending an email using the 'mailto' approach, using the 'mail_to' and 'url_launcher' Flutter packages. It has to open the client's Email app, but it works just fine. The Gmail API for Dart is terrible and there is no documentation, so I would suggest just taking another approach.

```
  // Send email using mail_to and url_launcher packages
```

sendEmail() async {

```
print('sendEmail');

final mailtoLink = Mailto(
  to: ['ashtonjonesdev@gmail.com'],
  subject: '$_subject',
  body: '$_message',
);
// Convert the Mailto instance into a string.
// Use either Dart's string interpolation
// or the toString() method.
await launch('$mailtoLink');
```

}